# How to fit columns height into body with Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm looking for a solution to fit the columns of Twitter Bootstrap into the Body. Like the example below. Is there a robust way to do it? Because if i'm trying it with height:100% or position absolute (and top:0, bottom:0, etc.) it doesn't work as expected (or i have a scrollbar).

So how can i fit the col's into the body height, but on mobile (col-xs-...) to fallback to the "normal" bootstrap usage?

Thanks a lot!

```
  Desktop view

  +---------------------------+---------------------+
  |         LOGO ETC          |    OTHER STUFF      |
  |         Height: ~20%      |    Height: ~20%     |
  +---------------------------+---------------------+
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  | Navigation |         Content                    |
  |    80%     |           80%                      |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  |            |                                    |
  +------------+------------------------------------+



  Mobile View:

  +---------------------------+
  |         LOGO ETC          |
  +---------------------------+
  |         OTHER STUFF       |
  +---------------------------+
  |                           |
  |         Navigation        |
  |                           |
  +---------------------------+
  |                           |
  |         Content           |
  |                           |
  |                           |
  +---------------------------+
```

Comment: You've got any code to provide? Would help a lot.

Comment: Could you please post your **relevant** HTML and CSS in the question?

Comment: Is your header static? or as you scroll it goes away?

Comment: Here's a simple code. Hope helps a little bit to understand, what i want...
thanks...

https://jsfiddle.net/antvxrqb/1/

Comment: here's a more useable example i think...
https://jsfiddle.net/antvxrqb/2/

but the problem on this is that it not correctly fits (the colored top div's) and got a horizontal scrollbar. also i'll have to remove any margin and padding that comes up with bootstrap.

has someone an idea for a cleaner solution? thanks

Comment: As already mentioned in my answer, you have to use media-queries or (if you really want that) some javascript to handle it. Here is a modified fiddle of yours: https://jsfiddle.net/antvxrqb/3/
Just note, you have to set a height in percent for all of your parent containers to be able to set a height for your desired container itself.

Comment: Thanks Aer0, i think i've got it... https://jsfiddle.net/antvxrqb/4/
is that a useable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there isn't any code coming up from you, here is a little example of how it could work.

https://jsfiddle.net/hwp9qw34/

You can simply add some customized `media-queries` to your `div`s. Another approach to deal with that would be the usage of Bootstraps `.visible-*-*` and `.hidden-*-*` classes. But note: This would totally end up in bloating up your html and redundant markup which would lead to a slow(er) performance.

Comment: thanks, it goes in the right direction... here's a fiddle (as you can see in my comments above) which maybe better explains what i'll want.. https://jsfiddle.net/antvxrqb/2/
 thank you

Answer (score 2):

Click Full page to view your desktop view.

You have to set the height of the body(parent of the div) to have the height in % of the div to work and in turn set the height of the html (parent of body).

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.div1,
.div2 {
  height: 40%;
}
.div3,
.div4 {
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1 col-xs-12 col-md-6">div1</div>
<div class="div2 col-xs-12 col-md-6">div2</div>
<div class="div3 col-xs-12 col-md-3">div3</div>
<div class="div4 col-xs-12 col-md-9">div4</div>
```

Comment: that looks great... but it doesn't work if you wrap it in the bootstrap container and row ... https://jsfiddle.net/dw440b6a/

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/thinhn1992/xb1js7cw/](https://jsfiddle.net/thinhn1992/xb1js7cw/) Try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">

   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">logo</div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">other stuff</div>         
   </div>

   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">navigation</div>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">content</div>         
   </div> 


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see here in my [bin](http://jsbin.com/cefetaparo/edit?html,output). If you look on snippet just make a full screen view.

```css
.divs{
  background:blue;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height:100px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class='container'>
    <div class="text-center col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 divs">
  logo
    </div>
    <div class="text-center col-sm-6 col-lg-6 divs">
  other stuff
    </div>
    <div class="text-center col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 divs">
  nav
    </div>
    <div class="text-center col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 divs">
  content
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```